# cannot match a server with double Ip address

Tags: nginx

I have a server with two ip: when i use nginx as Reverse Proxy for jboss7，
in order to prevent direct access use  ip address,(we have configured the dns),
i use configuration bellow:

```
# You may add here yourdefault_server;
# server {
#
server {
    listen *:80;
    server_name _;
    return 404;
}

server {

    listen  80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

root /usr/share/nginx/html;
index index.html index.htm;

server_name www.shikuaigou.com localhost;
charset utf-8;

location / {
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $http_x_forwarded_for;  
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;   
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_pass http://jboss;
}

location /doc/ {
    alias /usr/share/doc/;
    autoindex on;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    allow ::1;
    deny all;
}
}
server {
listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    rewrite "^/(.*)$" http://www.example.com/$1 permanent;
}

server {

    listen 12.34.56.78;

    server_name www.example.com;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $http_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_pass http://jboss;
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }
}
```

but only on ip can matche the server whitch return 404,the other one cannot match the

configuration **server_name _;**

which cause this?

Answer (score 1):

Because you have `listen 12.34.56.78;` so nginx chooses this server to process requests on `12.34.56.78`, since it is more specific for that IP.

Please, also note that `server_name _;` actually means nothing, except an incorrect domain name.

Reference:

- [Server names](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html)
- [How nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html)
- [The `listen` directive](http://nginx.org/r/listen)